# Azure backend ignoring meas_level=2

Tags: measurement, azure-quantum

I'd like to retrieve from IonQ QPU provided by Azure the  per-shot measurements.
Azure recommends the results are retrieved via Qiskit.
The standard Qiskit command for that is: `shots_mem_list=job.result().get_memory(0)` which  will deliver a list  of bit-strings: ['101011', '101111', '000100', '111100',...]

But to make it work the job needs to be submitted to the backend with 2 additional flags: meas_level=2 and memory=True.

```
 backend.run(circ, count=100, meas_level=2, memory=True)
```

However,  Azure is ignoring meas_level flag:

```
meas_level is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.quantum._client.models._models_py3.JobDetails'> and will be ignored
```

As a consequence  Qiskit result.get_memory(0) command produces an error:

```
qiskit.exceptions.QiskitError: 'No memory for experiment "0". Please verify that you either ran a measurement level 2 job with the memory flag set, eg., "memory=True", or a measurement level 0/1 job.'
```

Is it possible to invoke azure.quantum.backend with meas_level=2 argument to be passed to the backend?

Answer (score 1):

No, Azure Quantum doesn't support setting `memory=True` on a backend yet. See: https://github.com/microsoft/qdk-python/issues/225

The only workaround is to simulate the individual results by populating the memory on the client using the same probability distribution as the results from the job, something like:

```
result = backend.run(circuit, count=100).result()
memory = random.choices(list(result.keys()), weights=result.values(), k=100)
print(memory)
```

the values will be statiscally equivalent, but they are of course not the actual measurements that you got from the device.

Comment: I'm measuring on the real device and it is costly. The reason I want to activate this option is I want to re-analyze the measurements instead of submitting new jobs with smaller number of shots. Since 1+1/2+1/4+...=2 - it would save me 1/2 of the total cost. Would be great (for users) if Azure were to support memory=True.